# How do I configure which programs autostart when connecting to the internet?

Tags: settings, internet, auto-start

Right now skype starts, email clients send/receive.

I really don't want skype to start and login when I connect to 3G, but it's OK if I connect to wifi.

How do I configure which programs autostart when connecting to 3G / wifi?

(Sony Ericsson Xperia X8, NOT rooted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without root you only have the control the app developers give you: If an app allows you to configure this behaviour, you can do so -- otherwise you can't.

If your device were rooted, on the other hand, you'ld have several possibilities:

- Use [DroidWall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free) to define which apps may use 3g, which Wifi, which both, and which none (1st pic below)
- Use [LBE Privacy Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite) to do the same, and more (2nd pic)
- Use [Autorun Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun) to disable certain listeners of apps, so they no longer get informed about network changes (3rd pic; experienced users only!)

[image: Droidwall] [image: LBE Privacy Guard] [image: AutoRun Manager]

This is just a selection, and thus the list is very incomplete. As you already wrote your device is not rooted, it doesn't make sense to put all those details here; it's just to give you an idea what *would be* possible with root, not to elaborate all options ;)